# Azure Synapse CI/CD

Tags: azure, github, devops, azure-synapse, cicd

I have a one working azure synapse workspace, and i want to commit my sql scripts and notebooks (possibly python files) directly to github and and i want those changes to reflect on synapse studio and trigger the pools and show the output. i tried adding the files once i integrated my workspace with git, also those files were in json format.

I know synapse studio kinda works as an IDE where we directly create scripts in the development hub and run it through pools, but i wanted to see if we could reverse enginner this process.

Comment: @Syed_Imran , Do you want to develop your code outside Synapse Studio, commit it to Github, and have the changes reflected in Synapse Studio? Why would you want to work backward?

Comment: @ChenHirsh, as i stated in my question i want to know if there is any way to reverse engineer this process, (I have a requirement where i want to commit my scripts and files to github instead of synapse workspace directly)

Answer (score 0):

You can edit code outside Synapse workspace by using GitHub web or GitHub desktop application. You can then commit these changes to Github, and the changes will reflect in the branch you see in Synapse Studio.

If you want this code to be published to the live environment, to affect triggers, etc., the same way you would use the "publish" button in the Studio. You need to create a build pipeline. You can use Azure DevOps for that, see the details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/cicd/source-control

Comment: my github is updated once i integrate my workspace to github, but my scripts & files are in .json format, let's say if i want to update my scripts to github i'm not able to add those files directly as in raw format which are typically in (.py) extension.